# Fatal error: Call to undefined function getfilelist()

Tags: php

why i get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function getfilelist() in
>   /home/se7encla/public_html/dir.php on line 3

and how to resolve that?!

line 3 is

```
 $dirlist = getFileList("./Update/");
```

dir.php

```
 <?PHP
 // examples for scanning a directory called images
 $dirlist = getFileList("./Update/");
?>
```

echo.php

```
<?PHP
 // output file list as HTML table
  foreach($dirlist as $file) {
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td>{$file['name']}</td>\n";
echo "<td>{$file['Stream']}</td>\n";
echo "<td>{$file['size']}</td>\n";
 }
echo "\n";
?>
```

update.php

```
 <?PHP
  if(isset($_GET['action']) and ($_GET['action']=="list"))
{
require_once "./dir.php";
require_once "./echo.php";

 function getFileList($dir)
  {
// array to hold return value
$retval = array();

// add trailing slash if missing
if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

// open pointer to directory and read list of files
$d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  // skip hidden files
  if($entry[0] == ".") continue;
  if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) {
    $retval[] = array(
      "name" => "$dir$entry",
      "size" => 0,
       "Stream" => md5_file("$dir$entry")
    );
  } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) {
   $retval[] = array(
      "name" => "$entry",
      "size" => filesize("$dir$entry"),
     "Stream" => md5_file("$dir$entry")
    );
  }
  }
 $d->close();

  return $retval;
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: You aren't includng `update.php` from `dir.php`, are you? Use `include("update.php");` to fix that

Comment: the main file is update.php and this file include :require_once "./dir.php";
require_once "./echo.php";

Comment: and after add that code you say i get this errors:Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/se7encla/public_html/echo.php on line 3

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getfilelist() (previously declared in /home/se7encla/public_html/update.php:7) in /home/se7encla/public_html/update.php on line 7

Comment: Ah, I see, I didn't realize update.php is the main file. In that case, I'm not completely sure what's happening. Try moving the getFileList() function outside the `if` block, maybe the conditional is messing with the function getting loaded

Comment: no i do right that :<?PHP
  function getFileList($dir)
  {
if(isset($_GET['action']) and ($_GET['action']=="list"))
{
require_once "./dir.php";
require_once "./echo.php";


    // array to hold return value
    $retval = array(); .....   and now get blank page?!

Comment: No, I mean put the function to the bottom of the file, when the `if` has closed

Comment: i do that:<?PHP
require_once "./dir.php";
require_once "./echo.php";

  function getFileList($dir)
  {
    if(isset($_GET['action']) and ($_GET['action']=="list"))
     {
    // array to hold return value
    $retval = array();......  and in update.php?action=list every thing is ok but in simple link update.php i get now this error:  <?PHP
require_once "./dir.php";
require_once "./echo.php";

  function getFileList($dir)
  {
    if(isset($_GET['action']) and ($_GET['action']=="list"))
     {
    // array to hold return value
    $retval = array();

Comment: how to resolve that:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/se7encla/public_html/echo.php on line 3

Comment: Thank you for reply its don (resolved).